# SEGSEV, segmentation fault on ENTER opcode

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

(I'm writing in pure x86 assembly for NASM, not in C/C++.)

I'm getting a segmentation fault when the compiled binary runs - I'm aware this is an age old error message, but searching for this specific instance of a seg fault hasn't proved to be fruitful:

gdb suggests that the fault happened at `ENTER 616,0` at the beginning of a call. I believe it's the same as pushing the old `%rbp`, storing `%rsp` into `%rbp`, and decreasing `%rsp` for `616` bytes of local variables.

Does anyone with more experience have hints as to why a segmentation fault can happen here? It seems like a strange place for memory access issues - the only thing that comes to mind is that 616 might be a lot to decrease the value by, but other than that it's baffling me. Is there a limit on the size allowed (other than the total amount of memory available)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update:
If it helps, this isn't the end of a long series of recursive calls:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000000004005e0 in user_func ()
#1  0x0000000000400e69 in if4 ()
#2  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#3  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) frame 0
#0  0x00000000004005e0 in user_func ()

(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function user_partition:
=> 0x00000000004005e0 <+0>:     enterq $0x2b0,$0x0
   0x00000000004005e4 <+4>:     push   %r15
   0x00000000004005e6 <+6>:     push   %r12
   0x00000000004005e8 <+8>:     push   %r13
   0x00000000004005ea <+10>:    push   %r14
   ...
```

Update 2:
Since the backtrace seems to indicate a corrupted stack pointer, here's some relevant details on what each method call looks like:

```
user_func:                           
   ENTER      296, 0                         
   PUSH       R13      ; Saving any callee-saved registers used in main body   
   PUSH       R15     
   PUSH       R14     
   PUSH       R12     
   ; Only opcodes to MOV between temp registers and [ RBP - x ]
   MOV        RAX, 0                        
   POP        R12      ; Restoring the callee-saved registers    
   POP        R14
   POP        R15
   POP        R13
   LEAVE                                    
   RET
```

Is it possible that I've done something wrong here in terms of pushing / popping things? The POP before LEAVE seemed right to me...

Comment: Perhaps you simply have a stack overflow?  Where is the stack pointer in relation to the allocated stack size?

Comment: Hm, so for some context I'm writing a compiler, and running it without certain optimizations leaves the same ENTER 616,0 command but without the seg fault. Do you know how other commands might affect this call? How do I check the stack size?

Comment: Also, it might help that backtrace in gdb shows that there isn't an insanely large number of recursive calls, so I'm not too convinced of a stack overflow. (Updated question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values like `0x0000000000000` and `0xffffffffffff` in your backtrace indicate that you've trashed the stack at some point (overwritten a return value or similar).  It is likely that your stack pointer is garbage, hence a high likelihood that pushing to it will cause a seg-fault.

Comment: Turns out my issue had NOTHING to do dirty registers, an error elsewhere was simply causing the code to recurse forever. You were spot-on with the guess of "stack overflow." I'm going to mark this as the answer since you were so much help (and did indeed provide the answer, as a comment).